# the usage of about in sentence

Tags: grammar

> Man has used wheels for about 5000 years.

In this sentence, what is the grammar usage of "about"?
Is it an adjective or an adverb or a preposition?

Comment: As "nearly" or "almost", it's an adverb.

Answer (score 1):

Used with an amount or quantity, "about" is considered an adverb. It is sometimes called a "quantity adverb":

> Quantity adverbs modify the quantity or intensity of an adjective, a
>   verb, or another adverb. Quantity adverbs typically are placed
>   immediately before the words they modify. Some common quantity adverbs
>   are *almost, completely, especially, extremely, hardly, just, nearly,
>   only, quite, really, relatively*, and *very*.